# Creating multiple fields with ranks using arcpy

Tags: python, shapes, ranking, arcpy

What I have to do, create a field for each arrondise, and in each, rank each FID (which are part of the respective arrondise) by the size of its shape area. Something short of ranking per arrondisse(district) in terms of size.

Attribute table used can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXcvv.png), as I can't post images yet.

Currently, trying to rank each row which is part of a certain arrondise (ex. 1, 2) in terms of its shape area. So far, this is what I have:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/M1 Geomatique/Programmation II/Dossier"

fc = "zones_rattachement.shp"

try:
    fieldRoot = "RANG_R"
    for counter in range(1,20):
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldRoot + str(counter),'LONG')


    size_rank = 1
    field = "arrondisse"
    numlist = list(range(1,20))
    for num in numlist:
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, sort_fields="shape_area D")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fc, "NEW_SELECTION", field = num)
        for row in rows:
            row.setValue("RANG_R1", size_rank)
            size_rank += 1
            rows.updateRow(row)

except:
    arcpy.GetMessages()
```

What would you recommend me to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I find some sort of solution, an adaption after the very brilliant solution for adding ranks found [here](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/ranking-field-values/).